# U-Boot - 6x_bootscript not found

Tags: linux, openwrt

Здравствуйте, я думаю некоторые из Вас уже читали, что я пытался на основе [cubox-i](http://www.igorpecovnik.com/2014/08/19/cubox-i-hummingboard-debian-sd-image/) запустить OpenWRT. После маленькой консультации от одного из пользователей stackoverflow, я решил все же попробовать специально под HummingBoard, его можно найти также по ссылке выше, сделать образ OpenWRT.

После некоторых мучений я все же пришел к продвижению.

К сожалению все на прогрузки U-Boot и остановилось:

```
U-Boot 2014.07-00136-gf870252 (Sep 22 2014 - 09:17:11) 
6x_bootscript not found 
serial console at 115200, 8N1
details at http://boundarydevices.com/6q_bootscript 
no block devices found 
U-Boot >
```

я уже переходил по ссылке Выше а также знаю что такое `no block devicec found`. Сам линукс записывал по мануалу.

Comment: Знающих кто может помочь, нету?

Comment: Да есть скорее всего, но для начала попробуйте самый свежий U-Boot, сего года.